# Is my hard drive dead?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I have a 2TB internal HD and am running Ubuntu 14.04 on an SSD. The 2GB drive was divided into 2 partitions, one as NTFS and the other as ext4.

I'm currently unable to access either partition. Running gparted generates the following error messages:

```
Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb: Input/output error
Input/output error during read on /dev/sdb
```

After ignoring and cancelling through the various errors it shows the drive as 1.83Tb unallocated.

The gnome disk utility, Disks, however, shows the drive as having the following:

```
partition 1
windows_data
536 GB NTFS
64% full

partition 2
ubuntu_data
1.5TB Ext4
9.4% full
```

What I'm trying to determine is whether to write off the disk and bin it or is there any likelihood I can rescue it.

Comment: Doesn't Disks itself allow you to run a SMART test on that drive?

Answer (score 2):

Install `gsmartcontrol` and evaluate the SMART information that the drive can provide. Run the SMART drive diagnostics and try to eliminate a bad drive.

Install `testdisk` to try and recover your partitions without losing data. See http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step for a step-by-step intro on how to use testdisk.

## in `terminal`:

`sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install gsmartcontrol`  # start from Unity dashboard
   `sudo apt-get install testdisk`
    `sudo testdisk` # to start testdisk

Comment: Thanks for responding. I tried testdisk but it was unable to find any partitions, even using the deeper search facility. I'll have a go at installing gsmartcontrol.